# Enable report sorting but disable stable sort

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, visualize

Jaspersoft reports allow for stable sorting. You can sort by column a, then column b.

Is there a way to enable sorting, but disable stable / multi column sorting either at the report level or the Visualize.js level?

Comment: What do you mean by stable sort? Where do you apply it?

Comment: You can sort by column 1. Then you can sort by column 2, and it doesn't clear the sort flag from column1. If there are matches in the primary sort, the matches will be resolved by the secondary sort @Narcis